# Ubuntu 20.04: install both 32 bit and 64 bit libraries

Tags: dependencies, 64-bit, 32-bit, multiarch

My (newbie) Ubuntu 20.04 server is configured for both 32- and 64-bit architecture:

```
$ dpkg --print-architecture

amd64

$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures

i386
```

However, I can't seem to have both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the same library which apps depend on.

```
apt-get install libodbc1:i386
apt-get install libodbc1
```

When I install one, the other is removed. When I install the 32-bit version, apps (Plesk, VS Code) that need the 64-bit version break, and when I install the 64-bit version, apps (WineHQ) that need the 32-bit version break.

How do I install both to make all apps work?

**UPDATE**

When I run the following, I get the following:

```
$ sudo apt install libodbc1 libodbc1:i386
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libodbc1 : Breaks: libodbc1:i386 (!= 2.3.7) but 2.3.6-0.1build1 is to be installed
 libodbc1:i386 : Breaks: libodbc1 (!= 2.3.6-0.1build1) but 2.3.7 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And, when I run the following, I get the following:

```
$ apt policy libodbc1
libodbc1:
  Installed: 2.3.7
  Candidate: 2.3.7
  Version table:
 *** 2.3.7 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.3.6-0.1build1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using a newer version of `libodbc1` by Microsoft, which was not compatible with `libodbc1:i386`.

I disabled Microsoft packages URL, and downgraded `libodbc1` to version `2.3.6-0.1build1`, and `libodbc1:i386` installed just fine.

Everything seems to be working now. I just hope Microsoft products don't break in the future.

Answer (score 3):

For me, what worked was this:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt update
apt install libc6-i386
```

as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/541354/40048)

Answer (score 0):

Did you install multiarch-support?
If not, try:

```
sudo apt-get -y install multiarch-support:i386
```

Comment: This returns `E: Unable to locate package multiarch-support:i386` for me.